# What is SID when connecting silk central with SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, silk-central

I am trying to connect silk central application to a SQL Server database. 
Once I am on the database connection page of silk central, It will ask for following information.

```
DBMS type: 
Port:
Database/SID: 
Username:
Password:
```

What to fill in Database/SID, username and password field ?

```
DBMS type: SQL Server  
Port: 1433
Database/SID: ?
Username: ?
Password:  ?
```

Comment: The company themselves have documented how to complete this, please see: https://community.microfocus.com/t5/Silk-Central-Knowledge-Base/Making-a-new-SilkCentral-database-in-SQL/ta-p/1752005